# Android Activity Transition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, transition

I have implemented and app with many activities, in the beginning the transition from the first activity to the second has a very smooth left to right slide for the splash screen(1st activity) and at the same time a right to left for the second activity, that transition occurred without showing that black background of android since the slide trade very smooth. Then i've closed the ADT and on the next day when i maked some changes to the app the activity has changed to a fade out and fade in transition for all the activities that i create after. I have search the web for one week long and did not find the answer.

I tried to create my own transitions using "overridePendingTransition" but it does not have the same effect. I want to know how i can use the built in transitions in order the achieve the same results.

Here is some of my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    //Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent("com.gdd.appz.MAIN");
    Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
   }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Had you already set a transition effect between activities before you have made those changes?

Comment: No! this app is very simple so i just set the basic, i just dont have set any transition effect and the changes was not in these activities.

Comment: Then, try to use the built in transitions, like overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out). Use it after startActivity() call.

Comment: I've tried that but i just did not worked.